# How to install certificate in Istio ingress gateway in GKE

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

Using [GKE with integrated istio](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing), is it possible to use a google managed certificate for the ingress gateway?

When the cluster is created, the ingress is already present. I don't see how to inject other than by managing a secret and linking to the Istio gateway.

Is this a good way or do you know something simpler?

Answer (score 2):

Managing certs via optional secret (named: istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs) is a recommended way by Istio, as described [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/mount/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-with-a-file-mount-based-approach). The Istio gateway will load the secret automatically.

You can also do a re-deployment of default istio-ingressgateway with new certificates, aided with helm tool ([guide link here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/mount/#redeploy-istio-ingressgateway-with-the-new-certificates))

Official GCP documentation suggests also in that terms, to create a new ingress resources (see [Adding gateways](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing) paragraph), to avoid any customizations done to default Istio-GKE being wiped out during auto upgrades.

So the other option for you, is to create a custom-ingress-gateway with Google Managed certs, and link it later in Virtual Services, as explained in [this](https://istio.io/blog/2019/custom-ingress-gateway/) blog post. To ease creation of manifest file for custom ingress-gateway you can also use helm template command* from guide link above - "Redeploy istio-ingressgateway with the new certificates".

*Don't forget about changing its name in metadata in resulting file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually still strugling on this. Apparently there is no way for Istio to know that the cert has been updated (https://medium.com/@prune998/istio-1-0-2-envoy-cert-manager-lets-encrypt-for-tls-certificate-merge-7a774bff66c2).

Comment: For "custom-ingress-gateway" does this mean I can map a Virtual Service directly to an Ingress?